# Google Sheets - Trying to autofill user and time/date when checkbox clicked

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to autofill the next column with the user and datestamp after a checkbox is clicked, I'm only getting the user using the below, how do I get both, please and thank you very much, I'm a bit rusty on this stuff.

```
 /** @OnlyCurrentDoc */
function onEdit() {
 var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
 if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
   var r = s.getActiveCell();
    var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
   Logger.log(email);
   if( r.getColumn() == 3 ) { //checks the C column
    var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
   nextCell.setValue(email);
  if( r.getColumn() == 5 ) { //checks the E column
   var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
  if( nextCell.getValue() !== '' ) //is empty?
 nextCell.setValue(email),(new Date())
 .setNumberFormat ('MM/dd/yyyy HH:MMam/pm');
   } 
  }
 }
}
```

Tried the above, expecting the autofill to have email and date, only email being auto filled.

Answer (score 2):

Please find this code

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // Check if the active sheet is "Sheet1"
  if (sheet.getName() == "Sheet1") {
    var activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
    var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

    // Check if the edited cell is in column C
    if (activeCell.getColumn() == 3) {
      var nextCell = activeCell.offset(0, 1);

      // Set the value in column D to the email
      nextCell.setValue(email);

      // Get the cell in column E of the same row
      var dateCell = activeCell.offset(0, 2);

      // Set the value in column E to the formatted current date
      var currentDate = new Date();
      var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(currentDate, "GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mma");
      dateCell.setValue(formattedDate);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked flawlessly and I now see how I should have structured the code. Thank you very much!